# Trying to show custom success message and hide default success message in Django admin

Tags: django, django-forms

```html
<-- In admin.py I have a function it showing my custom message but also showing default success message how to stop default success message ??-->

from django.contrib import messages, admin
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
  self.message_user(request, "The message", level=messages.SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the response_add method in the ModelAdmin like this

```
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)
    .......
    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        msg = "Your message"
        self.message_user(request, msg, level=messages.SUCCESS)
        return self.response_post_save_add(request, obj)
```

Comment: Still, 2 messages are showing first our custom and default message -(it's not working)

Comment: it's working when I am inserting new data but what about when I am updating data that time it showing the default message

Comment: you need to override  another method  `reposne_change` for update like this in your ModelAdmin @vipul

Comment: . see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.response_change

Comment: def response_change(self, request, obj):
        msg = "Record updated sucessfully."
        self.message_user(request, msg, level=messages.SUCCESS)
        return self.response_post_save_change(request, obj)

Comment: This example overrides a ton of default behavior and may lead to unexpected results.