# I have a model form in django, whenever i submit the form i am getting both the custom success message and the default one how to suppress the default

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

```
obj.save()
messages.success(request,'{} is successfully updated'.format(obj.template_name))
```

here the obj.save() saves all the changes in database.
and then I am printing my custom message after it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705209/8401179

Comment: Can you please share the relevant view/form/...?

Comment: Hey thanks guys for trying to help me, @SANGEETHSUBRAMONIAM that didn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449233/how-to-prevent-changed-successfully-message-when-overriding-save-model-method
this worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def message_user(self, request, message, level=messages.INFO, extra_tags='',
                 fail_silently=False):
    pass
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    try:
        /some code
    except:
        /some code
    obj.save()
    messages.success(request,'{} is successfully updated'.format(obj.template_name))
    pass
```

This code should be in admin.py in the form class which you are trying to change.
Here we are overriding the message_user function which sends message to user using django.contrib.messages and we are adding our own custom message after saving the obj.

Thanks @Vladimir Godovalov - [How to prevent "Changed successfully" message when overriding save_model method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25449233/how-to-prevent-changed-successfully-message-when-overriding-save-model-method)